# Send not calling private method in Class or Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I am trying to create a class or module that I can then use to call a private method within that class / module.

I'm getting this error:
`NoMethodError (undefined method 'call' for MixPanelService:Class)`

When I try and do `MixPanelService.call(shop, "install")`

Here is my simplified code:

```
class MixPanelService

  def call(shop, event_type)
    send(event_type, shop)
  end

  private

  def install
    ap "do something"
  end

end
```

So then I tried with a module, and I get the following error:
`NoMethodError (undefined method 'install' for MixPanelService:Module)`

When I basically try the same with:
`MixPanelService.call(shop, "install")`

With the following code:

```
module MixPanelService
  module_function

  def call(shop, event_type)
    send(event_type, shop)
  end

  private

  def install
    ap "do something"
  end

end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: With the class `MixPanelService.call` won't work because `call` is an instance method (as is install); `MixPanelService.call` expects it to be a class method.

Comment: `module_function` makes `call` available as a class method. However, invoking `call` that way will send `install` to the same receiver, i.e. the class (or module). Since `install` is _not_ defined that way and only available as an instance method, this fails.

Comment: Here you're defining `call` as a messed up version of `send`. Any reason to not use `send`? It's worth noting that `call` has specific meaning as in `Proc#call`.

Comment: This is all great feedback, but how do you fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the class you've defined `call` as an instance method, but you're calling it as a class method. You can make it a class method using `def self.call`:

```rb
class MixPanelService
  def self.call(shop, event_type)
    send(event_type, shop)
  end

  def self.install(shop)
    # do something
  end
  private_class_method :install # ugly :(
end

# Call it like this:
MixPanelService.call(shop, 'install')
```

However that's not the best design. Using class methods and passing around arguments is cumbersome. You can work with instances but still have a class method to run everything. Take a look at this pattern:

```rb
class MixPanelService
  def self.call(shop, event_type)
    new(shop).call(event_type)
  end

  def initialize(shop)
    @shop = shop
  end

  def call(event_type)
    send(event_type)
  end

  private

  def install
    # Install something on `@shop`. Since it's an instance variable,
    # we don't need to pass it around via params! :)
  end
end

# Call it the same way as before:
MixPanelService.call(shop, 'install')
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because `module_function` don't support private methods such way. It copies public instance methods as self module methods and also make it as private instance

Probably it's better to compare this behavior in action and it's up to you choose what you need

```rb
# With module_function
module MyModule
  module_function

  def my_public_method
    puts "Hi from public"
    my_private_method
  end

  private

  def my_private_method
    puts "Hi from private"
  end
end

class MyIncludeClass
  include MyModule
end

class MyExtendClass
  extend MyModule
end

MyModule.my_public_method
# Hi from public
# undefined local variable or method `my_private_method' for MyModule:Module (NameError)

MyModule.my_private_method
# undefined method `my_private_method' for MyModule:Module (NoMethodError)

MyIncludeClass.new.my_public_method
# private method `my_public_method' called for #<MyIncludeClass:0x0000000104d766f8> (NoMethodError)

MyIncludeClass.new.my_private_method
# private method `my_private_method' called for #<MyIncludeClass:0x0000000104eb17c0> (NoMethodError)

MyExtendClass.my_public_method
# private method `my_public_method' called for MyExtendClass:Class (NoMethodError)

MyExtendClass.my_private_method
# private method `my_private_method' called for MyExtendClass:Class (NoMethodError)
```

```rb
# With extend self
module MyModule
  extend self

  def my_public_method
    puts "Hi from public"
    my_private_method
  end

  private

  def my_private_method
    puts "Hi from private"
  end
end

class MyIncludeClass
  include MyModule
end

class MyExtendClass
  extend MyModule
end

MyModule.my_public_method
# Hi from public
# Hi from private

MyModule.my_private_method
# private method `my_private_method' called for MyModule:Module (NoMethodError)

MyIncludeClass.new.my_public_method
# Hi from public
# Hi from private

MyIncludeClass.new.my_private_method
# private method `my_private_method' called for #<MyIncludeClass:0x0000000108afa790> (NoMethodError)

MyExtendClass.my_public_method
# Hi from public
# Hi from private

MyExtendClass.my_private_method
# private method `my_private_method' called for MyExtendClass:Class (NoMethodError)
```

```rb
# With class << self syntax
module MyModule
  class << self
    def my_public_method
      puts "Hi from public"
      my_private_method
    end

    private

    def my_private_method
      puts "Hi from private"
    end
  end
end

class MyIncludeClass
  include MyModule
end

class MyExtendClass
  extend MyModule
end

MyModule.my_public_method
# Hi from public
# Hi from private

MyModule.my_private_method
# private method `my_private_method' called for MyModule:Module (NoMethodError)

MyIncludeClass.new.my_public_method
# undefined method `my_public_method' for #<MyIncludeClass:0x0000000103fec6b8> (NoMethodError)

MyIncludeClass.new.my_private_method
# undefined method `my_private_method' for #<MyIncludeClass:0x00000001041929e0> (NoMethodError)

MyExtendClass.my_public_method
# undefined method `my_public_method' for MyExtendClass:Class (NoMethodError)

MyExtendClass.my_private_method
# undefined method `my_private_method' for MyExtendClass:Class (NoMethodError)
```

```rb
# With private_class_method
module MyModule
  def self.my_public_method
    puts "Hi from public"
    my_private_method
  end

  def self.my_private_method
    puts "Hi from private"
  end

  private_class_method :my_private_method
end

class MyIncludeClass
  include MyModule
end

class MyExtendClass
  extend MyModule
end

MyModule.my_public_method
# Hi from public
# Hi from private

MyModule.my_private_method
# private method `my_private_method' called for MyModule:Module (NoMethodError)

MyIncludeClass.new.my_public_method
# undefined method `my_public_method' for #<MyIncludeClass:0x00000001044f1870> (NoMethodError)

MyIncludeClass.new.my_private_method
# undefined method `my_private_method' for #<MyIncludeClass:0x000000010449bfb0> (NoMethodError)

MyExtendClass.my_public_method
# undefined method `my_public_method' for MyExtendClass:Class (NoMethodError)

MyExtendClass.my_private_method
# undefined method `my_private_method' for MyExtendClass:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution to the problem I was having. It all works fine now. I ended up using a `module` and `self` as below:

```
module MixPanelService
  module_function

  def self.call(shop, event_type)
    send(event_type, shop)
  end

  private

  def self.install(shop)
    # do something
  end

end
```

Comment: Note that `.install` isn't private. Try `MixPanelService.install(shop)` to verify. You can make it private by adding `private_class_method :install` just after the method's definition, before the module's last `end`.